# Voltage Conversion Module

Tags: voltage, resistors, analog

So firstly i'd like to say I'm relatively new with electrical engineering, nothing more than backyard experience. However I am a computer programmer so I can grasp the concepts fairly well.

One of the problems I run into quite frequently in automotive modification is the need to change one voltage to another, or rather, translate it.

An example of this could be:(non-specific numerical range as an example)

if (input_voltage == 1.1) { output_voltage = 1.1 }
elseif (input_voltage == 1.2) { output_voltage = 1.7 }
and so on.

Additionally, this scenario may occur: (non-specific numerical range as an example) 
if (input_ohm == 1) { output_ohm = 2 }
elseif (input_ohm == 3) { output_ohm = 7 }

An example of my current scenario can seen as follows. 
Fuel pump signal supply to the gauge is sent through a potentiometer on a float in the fuel tank. Signal is sent to the analog gauge where its displayed. 
Signal range can be anywhere from 0 (empty) to X. If i were to change the gauge, I would need to modify the signal to be within the parameters the new gauge expects while still utilizing the original sending unit.

My question is, is there some kind of user friendly programmable I/O logic board that I can use to achieve these types of conversion, or am I stuck with trying to create some rig of hardware to achieve the result?

Something like this would be perfect: 
http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?category=0&product_id=1012_2

However i don't believe this unit can output a regulated voltage, it appears to just be a switch.

Comment: Are you hoping to find a circuit with microvolt accuracy?

Comment: Doesnt need to be that refined. Im working with 12v DC circuts (Automobiles). Voltages for the electronics i work with generally range from 0.X to 9.X

Comment: Could you edit your post to give a more realistic example? The example in your post is non-trivial due to the _extreme_ accuracy required, and it sounds like you're not asking about such cases.

Comment: The type of circuit you'd need is an ADC (analog-to-digital converter) input, a microcontroller of some kind, and an DAC (digital-to-analog converter) output. Without more specific information, a better answer can't be given.

Comment: Is the translation completely arbitrary, or can it be expressed as a mathematical relationship? In the latter case, it may be possible to design analog circuits that approximate the relationship.

Comment: Sorry my answers aren't more specific to a scenario. Im asking based on more of a general scenario. Ive edited my answer to be more simplified.

Comment: @DanLaks that seems to be a great answer, would you recommend anything specific (See my updated question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your willing to work with a little hardware, some opamps and some resistors will do it

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcOsz7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>